# Nativescript carousel view plugins is throwing a runtime exception

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I am trying to use nativescript-carousel and nativescript-carousel-view plugins. I am successfully able to build the platforms using these two plugins. But at run time when I am trying to access the plugins in XML they both are throwing the exception:

**Error:**

```
com.tns.nativescriptException: Failed to find module.
```

PS: I can see the installed plugins under node_modules.

Comment: Have you rebuild app after adding plugin ? with `tns build`  ?

Comment: Hi Marek, Yes I rebuild the app after adding the plugin.